# asus transformer tf300tg - will this 3g work in uk/usa?

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer, 3g

I'm looking to buy the 3G version of the transformer TF300, but due to its availability I'm buying it from Taiwan. I currently live in the UK but next year I move to the USA so I'm trying to figure out if the 3G on it will work in both the UK and USA. The relevant specs are:

> "HSPA+ UL:5.76 Mbps/DL:21 Mbps |
>   3G :
>   WCDMA :
>   850/900/2100 |
>   2G :
>   GSM : 850/900/1800/1900"

I'm having trouble figuring out if this would work in other countries. Can anyone help me out? I found a wiki page titled 'UMTS frequency bands' which looks like what I need but I still can't figure it out, haha. My UK sim card is with Orange at the minute but I'll obviously be changing it when I go to the USA. Thank you!

Comment: Just look at which US carriers support 850/900/2100 3G.